# How to get Apple User Name-Surname and Email after getting authToken with Xamarin Essentials Web Authenticator

Tags: web, xamarin.forms, apple-sign-in, authenticator, xamarin.essentials

I want to get email and user name and surname etc.. from Apple after Xamarin Froms Essentials Web Authenticator. I get only WebAuthenticatorResult which contains only token, refresh token and token Id. How can I get user info with this tokens? I use Restful  Web Api with asp net core 3.1 as well.

Can you please help me? Apple documentation is not clear and is so confusing. Please HELP...  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you can get those user information from the [WebAuthenticatorResult.Properties Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.essentials.webauthenticatorresult.properties?view=xamarin-essentials).

If you can't, you can implement the Apple SignIn by yourself as mentioned [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/platform/sign-in-with-apple/android-ios-sign-in#a-cross-platform-sign-in-service), you can get those information by using DependencyService in Xamarin.forms:

```
public interface IAppleSignInService
{
    bool Callback(string url);

    Task<AppleAccount> SignInAsync();
}
```

And in iOS project:

```
public async Task<AppleAccount> SignInAsync()
{
    // Fallback to web for older iOS versions
    if (!Is13)
        return await webSignInService.SignInAsync();

    AppleAccount appleAccount = default;

#if __IOS__13
    var provider = new ASAuthorizationAppleIdProvider();
    var req = provider.CreateRequest();

    authManager = new AuthManager(UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow);

    req.RequestedScopes = new[] { ASAuthorizationScope.FullName, ASAuthorizationScope.Email };
    var controller = new ASAuthorizationController(new[] { req });

    controller.Delegate = authManager;
    controller.PresentationContextProvider = authManager;

    controller.PerformRequests();

    var creds = await authManager.Credentials;

    if (creds == null)
        return null;

    appleAccount = new AppleAccount();
    appleAccount.IdToken = JwtToken.Decode(new NSString(creds.IdentityToken, NSStringEncoding.UTF8).ToString());
    appleAccount.Email = creds.Email;
    appleAccount.UserId = creds.User;
    appleAccount.Name = NSPersonNameComponentsFormatter.GetLocalizedString(creds.FullName, NSPersonNameComponentsFormatterStyle.Default, NSPersonNameComponentsFormatterOptions.Phonetic);
    appleAccount.RealUserStatus = creds.RealUserStatus.ToString();
#endif

    return appleAccount;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Find SignInAsync() method In iOS project:

look for AppleProfile object, the user full names is actually retrieved but the code you have to format it and extract Name is not working, you'll have to manually get  GivenName and FamilyName from FullName object like below:

```
var appleAccount = new AppleProfile();
```

appleAccount.Token = new NSString(creds.IdentityToken, NSStringEncoding.UTF8).ToString();

```
        appleAccount.Email = creds.Email;
        appleAccount.UserId = creds.User;
        appleAccount.Name = creds.FullName.GivenName + " " + creds.FullName.FamilyName;
        appleAccount.RealUserStatus = creds.RealUserStatus.ToString();
```